Authenticación fallida JavaMailAPI
Estoy realizando una API sencilla utilizando JavaMail que al consumir método post se envie un mail con la información elegida.
Si envio las credenciales hardcodeadas el proyecto funciona correctamente. El problema aparece cuando reemplazo las credenciales por variables de entorno en mi archivo .env.
Contenido de mi archivo .env (obviamente al momento de usar la app las intercambio por las correctas, es solamente a modo de ejemplo para la publicacion):
#Mail User configuration
MAIL_USER=ejemplo@gmail.com
MAIL_PASS=123

Contenido del application.properties del proyecto
spring.config.import=optional:file:.env
spring.application.name=SpringBootMailSender

spring.mail.username=${MAIL_USER}
spring.mail.password=${MAIL_PASS}

Contenido de mi application config
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mail")
@Getter @Setter
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private String username;
    private String password;

}

Clase donde envio las credenciales a traves de inyeccion de dependencias de Application Config
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender(){

    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);
    mailSender.setUsername(appConfig.getUsername());
    mailSender.setPassword(appConfig.getPassword());


    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return mailSender;
}

El error que recibo por consola al hacer la peticion post es el siguiente:
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
2024-08-11T16:21:00.489-03:00 ERROR 20164 --- [SpringBootMailSender] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed] with root cause

jakarta.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d9443c01a7336-200bb9b2f81sm25423135ad.150 - gsmtp

Cabe aclarar que en mi .env tengo una credencial que proporciona Gmail para permitir los ingresos a mi cuenta a traves de APIs.

This question is similar to: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

En Intellij IDEA configuré las variables en la configuración del IDE en Path variables.
Cuando realmente la solución para que funcione en este caso era configurar las Environment variables en la sección de Run/Debug application como se detalla en la imagen.

